# Current Level of Microphone Input

Tags: linux, shell, audio, alsa

How can I get the current audio input level of a microphone via a shell command under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

I checked out amixer to set the volume but could not find a way to get the audio input level at the time of the shell call.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the level of the input signal, you have to actually record from the input device.
Use the `-d 1` parameter for `arecord` to get a short file.

To read the level of the data in that file, use something like `sox recordedfile.wav -n stat`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above answer, to get the maximum amplitude:

```
arecord -qd 1 volt && sox volt -n stat &> volt.d && sed '4q;d' volt.d
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want.